# Resources on the continuity and discontinuity debate of Ezekiel 1-39 and 40-48

Tags: ezekiel, authorship, source-criticism, reference-request

I am writing a research paper regarding the continuity of Ezekiel 1–39 and 40–48, I am trying to prove that the author of Ezekiel 1–39 is the same figure 40–48. I am trying to find both, the proponents who are against this theory, and those who are for.

So far I have found these proponents who are against the continuity theory:

- G. R. Berry
- W. R. Aytoun
- J. B. Harford
- S. Tuell

However I fail to find these people online. Can someone recognize those I mentioned above? If so, please provide links or their full name so I can find a relevant paper from them.

Moreover, if you know of some other proponents who are against the "continuity" who can also bring some good arguments against this theory.

Comment: I edited to cleanup the question a little bit, but it would be helpful if you could [edit] a bit more to clear up the confusion around which names you found were for or against this theory and any information about where you found these names as a starting place for research.

Comment: My issues here. (1) "Continuity" is not concerned with whether "`Ezekel in chapters 1–39 is the same figure as in 40–48`" -- of course they're the same *figure*. (2) The issue is one of supposed *authorship*, i.e., whether the book is a unified whole or literary "composite", with chunks produced at different periods. (3) This sounds like a "homework" question"! Reading [recent technical commentaries](https://www.bestcommentaries.com/ezekiel/) will quickly orient you to the arguments, as will [Tuell's *Law of the Temple in Ezekiel 40-48*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6ZASAQAAIAAJ).

Answer (score 1):

G.R. Berry is George R. Berry and he has published a paper that you can find at https://www.jstor.org/stable/3259177

W.R. Aytoun is William Edmondstoune Aytoun and also has a paper that references Ezekiel frequently at http://www.jstor.org/stable/3260109

J.B. Harford is John Battersby Harford and has written a book, Studies in the Book of Ezekiel, which you can find at [https://www.amazon.com/Studies-Book-Ezekiel-Battersby-Harford/dp/1107649463](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107649463)

S. Tuell is Steven Tuell, and has written a book, Ezekiel, which can be found here [https://www.amazon.com/Ezekiel-Understanding-Commentary-Steven-2008-12-01/dp/B01F7XCJ3K/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1519525512&sr=1-4&keywords=Ezekiel+by+Tuell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01F7XCJ3K)

I would also recommend the writings of Shalom Spiegel, who has a paper published here http://www.jstor.org/stable/1507763

In general, jstor.org is an excellent place to search for more on this subject. Another good resource is brill.com, which lists some promising publication on the topic.